# How do I view content using an administrative theme like Seven, when logged in as administrator?

Tags: 8

I can't view nodes using the Seven theme as administrative theme. When I am logged in as administrator, I can only view management pages with Seven, but no content pages.

I thought that the settings on this page should be sufficient.

> [image: screenshot]

How do I set an administrative theme like Seven to view nodes when I am logged in as administrator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drupal doesn't treat Content/Node view page as admin pages even after enabling "**Use the administration theme when editing or creating content**" setting on "**Admin => Appearance**" Page. This is just a setting allowed by Drupal Core. Node module uses this setting and alter Content/Note edit, delete, revision, etc. page URLs so Drupal can treat these path as Admin path.

You'll have to [alter route](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones) defined by Core's **Node** module. You can do this by implementing [`alterRoutes()`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones) and tell Drupal to treat Content View page as admin URLs. Check example below:

```
namespace Drupal\example\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.node.canonical')) {
      // Node module has option to define all path as admin path,
      // where path has "_node_operation_route" option set to TRUE.
      $route->setOption('_node_operation_route', TRUE);
      // Below line define path as admin path.
      // $route->setOption('_admin_route', TRUE);
    }
  }

}
```

If **Use the administration theme when editing or creating content** setting is enabled then, the Node module checks if any path has `_node_operation_route` option set to `TRUE`. If yes, it alters the path and set `_admin_route` option to `TRUE` so the path will be treated as an **admin path** (and then you will see it as in an admin theme, which is in this case, Seven).

If this doesn't work you can specifically set `_admin_route` option to `TRUE` for Content/Node View (`entity.node.canonical`) page programatically (check commented code).